# how can i check the cpu free limits in ec2 micro instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, cpu, cpu-usage

I have a micro-instance in amazon, 
I run a few tasks there and I wanted to know if there is a way to check the CPU consuming in order to know how much CPU I have left before I'll cross the limit and start paying for it.

For example, app engine shows you in a simple way how much CPU you have left until you will start paying for extra cpu usage.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: What does this have to do with App Engine?

Answer (score 1):

cloudwatch is built into AWS and provides CPU, network and memory usage. http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/

Basic monitoring is available in the free tier.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitoring your instance with [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)